# Issues with WildFly 10.10 and Eclipse JSF application

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I am testing my first JSF 2.2 app with WildFly 10.10 inside eclipse. When I run the app for the first time it worked fine. Then I made changes to the managed bean (added another attribute) and got an error.

I fixed the error, stopped the server, remove the application from the server then deployed it again (am doing all the add and remove inside Eclipse Neon).

After deploying the app again, I get the same error as previous in the browser. I decided to remove the attribute I added from the managed bean and then redeploy the app. I still get the same Exception error.

After removing and adding the app to the server several times I get the same Exception errors in the browser all the time.

It shows that the previous error is hidden somewhere in the server and it keeps on showing although there are no errors in my application regardless of the number of times I have redeployed it.

At least after removing the added attribute, the application has to work like when I first deployed it.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: _"How can i fix this annoying issue?"_ Start by reading [tour] and [ask] and [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Posting the exceptions would help.